# Attempting Join and getting Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'audio_links'. Choices are: (none)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to do a Join on two tables - would like to return all data from both ReleasesAll and AudioLinks.

**Error**

> FieldError at /api/release/0
>
> Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'audio_links'. Choices
>   are: (none)

**models.py**

```
class ReleasesAll(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    all_artists = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    remixers = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    format = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    label_no_country = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'releases_all'

class AudioLinks(models.Model):
    release = models.ForeignKey('ReleasesAll', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='release_id')
    track_number = models.IntegerField()
    track_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    m3u_link = models.TextField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'audio_links'
```

**views.py**

```
class ListReleaseDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = ReleasesAll.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReleasesSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            a_release = self.queryset.select_related('audio_links__release_id').get(pk=kwargs['release_id'])
            return Response(ReleasesSerializer(a_release).data)

        except ReleasesAll.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data = {
                    "message": "{} does not exist".format(kwargs["release_id"])
                },
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
```

If I remove the `select_related` then the query works

Answer (score 3):

You should use `prefetch_related` for multiple relations. Also argument of `prefetch_related` should be `related_name` value, or `audiolinks_set` in your case:

```
a_release = self.queryset.prefetch_related('audiolinks_set').get(pk=kwargs['release_id'])
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key
>   and one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this returns `Cannot find 'audio_links_set' on ReleasesAll object, 'audio_links_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`

Comment: @Franco sorry. It should be `audiolinks_set` not `audio_links_set`.

Comment: Thanks again @neverwalkaloner. This removes the error - it now returns the data from `ReleasesAll` but it still doesnt return the data from `audiolinks`.

Comment: @Franco did you add `audiolinks_set` as serializer field? Check this part of the docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: Serializer field is `class ReleasesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
  model = ReleasesAll
  fields = '__all__'`

Comment: @Franco To see related links you should explicitly add `audiolinks_set` field to your serializer, details described in the link above.